# rc.local file not working raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

This is the contents of my `/etc/rc.local` file. It is supposed to run on login on my raspberry pi, yet it just logs in in (as I'm using auto login) and then does nothing, i.e. it just sits there with `pi@raspberrypi ~$_` waiting for a command. I have no idea why it's not working nor any experience with bash scripts.

It should mount a usb then run a file on said usb but it doesn't.

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    #
    # rc.local
    #
    # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
    # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
    # value on error.
    #
    # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
    # bits.
    #
    # By default this script does nothing.


    sudo /bin/mount /dev/sda1 /media/robousb
    sudo python media/robousb/Robopython/usercode_old.py

    exit 0
```

Answer (score 5):

I assuming you're running Raspbian, which is pretty much Debian.

`rc.local` runs as root before login, so you don't need or want `sudo`; it may be causing an error, hence nothing happening.

User-level commands that run for any user when they log in (unlike rc.local, which runs before login) can be put into `/etc/bash.bashrc`. That may be more applicable to your situation, at least the second command.

Login commands for the pi user only can be put into `/home/pi/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. In Raspbian forum is the solution:

Just change the first row from `#!/bin/sh -e` to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Ivan X is right. You don´t need sudo command.

Comment: This trick does not work for me on my Raspberry Pi 4B

Answer (score 2):

I don't know raspberry-pi but you could try to write something into a file to see if the file is running or not. For example :

```
touch /tmp/test.txt
echo "$(date) => It's running" > /tmp/test.txt
```

If it doesn't work, I know that on some OS (fedora, rhel, centos for example), the path of that file is `/etc/init.d/rc.local`. It doesn't cost anything to try this path ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem with RPi3/Jessie.

I suggest you to launch your script in the bashrc by doing

```
sudo emacs /home/pi/.bashrc
```

In my case i wrote at the EOF:

```
bash /home/pi/jarvis/jarvis.sh -b &
```

And that works well at each startup.